# Masonry - Divs don't align

Tags: jquery, css, masonry

I am trying to create a masonry layout for a product page on my website. There is one square image with `width: 50%;` and then there should be 4 square images each with `width: 25%` which stack on top of one another.

This is what I have achieved so far: 
https://prism-ferret-k6wy.squarespace.com/shop/

As you will see there are two images beneath that can fit into the empty space that's available.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/dwinnbrown/pen/aQmOVR

This is my Javascript:

```
$('.ProductList-grid').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.ProductList-item',
            percentPosition: true
          });
```

and my CSS:

```
.ProductList .ProductList-item:nth-child(5n-4) {
        width: 50% !important;
    }


.ProductList .ProductList-item {
        float: none !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        width: 25% !important;
    }
```

This is how it should look:
[image]

Comment: Would you mind creating a fiddle for us with mock-images, so we can reproduce it more easily?

Comment: @Marco I have just added an image above but can try to create a fiddle

Comment: The website looks good. Just wanna know are you using bootstrap? Provide us with a fiddle link.

Comment: @Marco https://codepen.io/dwinnbrown/pen/aQmOVR

Comment: @krishna_tandon https://codepen.io/dwinnbrown/pen/aQmOVR

Comment: Just one more question, the image provided above and matching with the website link, is the UI will always be the same or small size images can exceed from 4. Will there always be one image for large size and rest 4 images of small size?

Comment: @krishna_tandon yes it will always be like this except for on mobile but I am comfortable handling that with a media query. Just need to get this functionality to work on desktop with Masonry.

Comment: Have a look at this link
https://codepen.io/krishnatandon1208/pen/BGLood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a grid-sizer to determine the columnWidth also works:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pQEJXV

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- width of .grid-sizer used for columnWidth -->
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2">1
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.grid-item:first-of-type {
  background-color: pink !important;
}

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 25%;
}

.grid-item {
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
}

.grid-item--width2 {
  width:50%;
}

.grid-item--height2{
  height:300px;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: green;
}
.grid-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.container').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
    percentPosition: true
  });
});
```

Documentation to responsive layout: https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html#responsive-layouts

[image]

Comment: Divs 3 and 5 are now placed beneath the main row at the top. The screenshot I attached shows what I'm aiming for it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
          <div class="grid-item">1</div>
          <div class="small-size">
                 <div class="grid-item">2</div>
                 <div class="grid-item">3</div>
                 <div class="grid-item">4</div>
                 <div class="grid-item">5</div>
          </div>
   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid-item:first-of-type {
  background-color: pink !important;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  height: 300px;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: green;
}
.grid-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}

.small-size {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 width: 50%;
}

.small-size .grid-item {
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.container').masonry({
    percentPosition: true,
    gutter: 10
  });
});
```

Comment: It works. Actually in your codepen link I found that u are using 
 itemSelector: '.grid-item'.

I removed this because that was not making the divs work as it requested. 
Maybe, Masonry is a requirement for you. Still, I will say this might work fine.

Comment: The line `itemSelector: '.ProductList-item',` has been removed from the JS which stops masonry from working.

Comment: So, is removing this line fixes the issue, without modifying the html/css?

Comment: No it doesn't fix the issue alone by removing that line